# Using XSLT to transform an xml so that a recurring node gets a unique name

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

Little addition, the example is a part of a larger xml, hope i clarified it.

I've got the following part of an xml file:

```
<smartdocuments_root_node xmlns="http://com.logica.digimeente.zaaksysteem">
<Zaak>
<ZaakNummer>21773</ZaakNummer>
<ZaakID>21768</ZaakID>
<Titel>Melding klein evenement De grote Kompanjie Barbeque!</Titel>
<Kenmerken>
<Kenmerk>
<KenmerkType>Starttijd evemenent</KenmerkType>
<Omschrijving>Starttijdevemenent</Omschrijving>
<Waarde>15:00</Waarde>
</Kenmerk>
<Kenmerk>
<KenmerkType>evement namens</KenmerkType>
<Omschrijving>evement namens</Omschrijving>
<Waarde>De Kompanjie</Waarde>
</Kenmerk>
<Kenmerk>
<KenmerkType>Datum evenement</KenmerkType>
<Omschrijving>Datumevenement</Omschrijving>
<Waarde>20171101</Waarde>
</Kenmerk>
</Kenmerken>
</Zaak>
</smartdocuments_root_node>
```

What i would to like to get is:

```
    <smartdocuments_root_node xmlns="http://com.logica.digimeente.zaaksysteem">
<Zaak>
<ZaakNummer>21773</ZaakNummer>
<ZaakID>21768</ZaakID>
<Titel>Melding klein evenement De grote Kompanjie Barbeque!</Titel>
<Kenmerken>
<Kenmerk1>
<KenmerkType>Starttijd evemenent</KenmerkType>
<Omschrijving>Starttijdevemenent</Omschrijving>
<Waarde>15:00</Waarde>
</Kenmerk1>
<Kenmerk2>
<KenmerkType>evement namens</KenmerkType>
<Omschrijving>evement namens</Omschrijving>
<Waarde>De Kompanjie</Waarde>
</Kenmerk2>
<Kenmerk3>
<KenmerkType>Datum evenement</KenmerkType>
<Omschrijving>Datumevenement</Omschrijving>
<Waarde>20171101</Waarde>
</Kenmerk3>
</Kenmerken>
</Zaak>
</smartdocuments_root_node>
```

Or rename the Kenmerk node with the value inside `<KenmerkType>`.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you quite sure you want to do this? That kind of XML is a devil to work with (even if you adapt it to be well formed): no-one will thank you for putting it into such form.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with an `identity template` that copies the input data as is.

```
<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

The `<Kenmerk>` element needs to be modified to `<Kenmerk1>`, `<Kenmerk2>` and so on. *Please note there **should not be a space in the node name*** and hence value of `<KenmarkType>` cannot be appended. In order to rename the nodes, you can create a variable using the node name and append the position of the node to it.

```
<xsl:variable name="newNodeName" select="concat(local-name(), position())" />
```

**EDIT**
The modified input XML now has a root element with a **namespace**.

```
<smartdocuments_root_node xmlns="http://com.logica.digimeente.zaaksysteem">
```

This indicates that all the elements belong to this namespace and have to be identified using an alias for the namespace when accessed in XSLT. Here an alias `abc` has been used as an example.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:abc="http://com.logica.digimeente.zaaksysteem" >
```

The elements have then to be accessed using the alias.

```
<xsl:template match="abc:Kenmerk">
```

Below is the complete XSLT.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:abc="http://com.logica.digimeente.zaaksysteem" >
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="abc:Kenmerk">
        <xsl:variable name="newNodeName" select="concat(local-name(), position())" />
        <xsl:element name="{$newNodeName}">
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output

```
<smartdocuments_root_node xmlns="http://com.logica.digimeente.zaaksysteem">
    <Zaak>
        <ZaakNummer>21773</ZaakNummer>
        <ZaakID>21768</ZaakID>
        <Titel>Melding klein evenement De grote Kompanjie Barbeque!</Titel>
        <Kenmerken>
            <Kenmerk1>
                <KenmerkType>Starttijd evemenent</KenmerkType>
                <Omschrijving>Starttijdevemenent</Omschrijving>
                <Waarde>15:00</Waarde>
            </Kenmerk1>
            <Kenmerk2>
                <KenmerkType>evement namens</KenmerkType>
                <Omschrijving>evement namens</Omschrijving>
                <Waarde>De Kompanjie</Waarde>
            </Kenmerk2>
            <Kenmerk3>
                <KenmerkType>Datum evenement</KenmerkType>
                <Omschrijving>Datumevenement</Omschrijving>
                <Waarde>20171101</Waarde>
            </Kenmerk3>
        </Kenmerken>
    </Zaak>
</smartdocuments_root_node>
```

Comment: Thanks alot, i added a little information and are really struggling to get this to work. Really appreciate if you can help.

Comment: The updated input XML now contains a namespace, which needs to be handled by the XSLT for identifying the elements. Please see the updated answer and also the explanation for handling namespaces.